# How to go about sorting 'trending' posts in the model?

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models

I have a `Post` model for user posts, and also a `PostScore` model to track the score of that `Post` in order to sort the queryset by `trending`, similar to reddit's 'hot':

```
class PostScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='score')
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    hot = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How would I go about the `hot` field? I'm not really asking about the algorithm for sorting them, but rather how to use my model in order to utilize the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This to the model:

```
popularity = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

This to the view for one Post:

```
from django.db.models import F
...
post.score.popularity = F('popularity') + 1
post.score.save()
```

This to the view with List of Posts:

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by('-score__popularity')
```

It's pretty basic logic, but we use it on several projects. For example this one: https://www.sahmri.org/library/?&popular=1

Comment: Can you tell me how the `F` is working here and how exactly the Posts are being ranked? Where do my `upvotes` and  `downvotes` come in?

Comment: An F() object represents the value of a model field. It makes it possible to refer to model field values and perform database operations using them without actually having to pull them out of the database into Python memory. Basically optimisation. If you want to have posts ranked by upvotes minus downvoats, you'll just need on every upvote or downvote to update the popularity. Same way with an F object.

Comment: Do you also know how to update fields over time? For example say a Post score is currently 450. I want to decrease the score by 5 every minute, any idea how I can do that? If not i'll ask a seperate question.

Comment: Either just cron job to the same application. Or a Celery task.

Comment: By the way, reddit's algorithm is on their public repo. Check it out. It's pretty complicated.